# p_create failed: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I am trying to create several RequestChannels (pipes)

Here I make the main channel:

```
pid_t controlPID;
cout << "CLIENT STARTED:" << endl;

controlPID = fork();
if(controlPID == 0 ){
    execl("./dataserver", (char*) NULL);
}
else{
cout << "Establishing control channel... " << flush;
RequestChannel chan("control", RequestChannel::CLIENT_SIDE);
cout << "done." << endl;
}
```

Here I make the several channels: (w = 10 or user input)

```
RequestChannel* channels[w];
    for(int i = 0; i < w; i++){
        string reply = chan.send_request("newthread");
        channels[i] = new RequestChannel(reply, RequestChannel::CLIENT_SIDE);
        channels[i]->cwrite("hello"); //write the request hello in request channel buffer.
    }
```

At first it worked several times, but gradually some channels were made and others got...

```
Reading next request from channel (control) ... done (control).
New request is newthread
p_create failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Eventually no threads were made.
What's happening? How can I fix this?
I look forward to your help.

Comment: E_NOTENOUGHCODE. In the code you have provided there is no any thread creation at all. BTW, your have very inconsistent style of formatting your code.